# How to prevent my cat from stealing my glasses

Tags: cats, behavior, training

While I have quality time (laying on bed and petting, them grooming me etc.) with my kittens one of them attempts to steal glasses out of my face and chew on them. She is very persistent but she doesn't seem to car in other situations - for example when glasses just lie on night table - at least for now. From what I understand that is sign of affection as glasses have a strong smell of daddy but I'm afraid as they are relatively valuable and hard to replace item. How can I redirect that behavior (I don't mind her playing with my hair for example).

Comment: buy him his own glasses!

Answer (score 4):

Kittens won't learn if they don't have boundaries. Playing with people's heads is a risky business – maybe not now when she is a kitten, but certainly when she gets older. It's all fun and games until she gets a bit overexcited and bites your face, or scratches your eye. I don't think you will be successful in training her to not play with your glasses if you continue to let her play with your hair, or any other part of your face.

Play with her in other ways instead, such as with toys. Reward her when she does not play with your face. Turn away and ignore her when she tries to play with your face. Basically, set some boundaries. Ignoring a kitten can be punishment enough when she misbehaves.

Answer (score 1):

Make a loop of tape, stick it to your glasses (the part they like to chew on), and leave it on the night table while you observe. Chances are that once a kitten gets stuck on the tape, it will never go near your glasses again. Repeat the process until all kittens have learned the lesson.

Only do this when you're around to help free the kittens from the tape. (Getting something stuck in their fur really upsets cats.)